# Organize C++ project in multiple folders in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2019

I want to create some folders in a project in visual studio 2019 to classify the files I use. I know that there is an equivalent called a filter. but it does not appear in the original directory as a folder. and when I tried to create some folders manually in the original directory. The file explorer in vs doesn't accept them. So I want to know an efficient way for that problem.

Comment: File system folders and filters (folder-like things in Solution Explorer) are unrelated. You can have files in different folders and the same filter, or in different filters and the same folder. I don't know of a  way to keep the two in sync automatically. You can certainly organize files into file system folders, then add them to the project, then move them to filters with the same names as those folders.

Comment: It's a good idea. Thanks, I will try it.